# Cant run a php file from var folder

Tags: php, apache2

I installed LAMP but still when i try to access a folder in var it says 404 not found I want to start "php" but it is stopping me can any one help. Actually when I type 127.0.0.1 I don't get page saying I works I get a page saying 
Index of /
index.php.save

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is in var/www/..
if still can't locate check your  in apache default.conf file..!